# How to append a value in a column in azure table storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I currently have an existing item inside the table storage
partitionkey = test, rowkey = bob, number= 911
now lets say i want to test to see if there is a value under the column name for this individual, if there is then append it with another number separated by ;

I have tried InsertOrMerge() but it replaces the value, I want the value to be appended in the column not removed.

Edit: Heres the code I tried

```
string tableName = "test2";
var batch = new TableBatchOperation();
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = 
CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(new 
TableClientConfiguration());
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
CustomerEntityTwo test = new CustomerEntityTwo("test", "bob")
{
  number= "119"

};
batch.InsertOrMerge(test);
table.ExecuteBatch(batch);
```

I know im not doing it right, I dont know exactly the proper way to append the 119 to the existing number value, but I would like it to be 911;119 under the 'number' column.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: sorry I added it now.

Answer (score 1):

`InsertOrMerge` operation does not work the way you think. It would create an entity if it does not exist or merge the attributes with existing attributes (adding new attributes, updating existing attribute values and not touching the missing attributes) if the entity exist.

In your scenario, you want to check if an attribute is present in an entity. If the attribute is present, you want to take the existing value of that attribute, append a new value to that item and then save that attribute again.

For this, first you would need to fetch that entity from the storage, compare the value with the new value, update the value and then call `Merge` operation on that entity.

For example, see the sample code below:

```
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=acccount-key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;");
        var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = client.GetTableReference("test");
        var partitionKey = "test";
        var rowKey = "bob";
        var valueToCheck = "119";
        var insertOrMergeEntity = true;
        var op = TableOperation.Retrieve(partitionKey, rowKey);
        var result = table.Execute(op);
        var entity = result.Result as DynamicTableEntity;
        if (entity == null)
        {
            entity = new DynamicTableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey);
        }
        if (entity.Properties.ContainsKey("number"))
        {
            var numberAttributeValue = entity.Properties["number"].StringValue;
            if (numberAttributeValue.IndexOf(valueToCheck) < 0)
            {
                numberAttributeValue += "; " + valueToCheck;
                entity.Properties["number"] = new EntityProperty(numberAttributeValue);
            }
            else
            {
                insertOrMergeEntity = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            entity.Properties.Add("number", new EntityProperty(valueToCheck));
        }
        if (insertOrMergeEntity)
        {
            var mergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);
            table.Execute(mergeOperation);
        }
```